# DD-WRT (pptp-client): Automatically add routes and DNS info when connected to VPN?

Tags: routes, dns, vpn, router

I'm using DD-WRT's PPTP client to connect to a VPN. On the Services / PPTP Client configuration page, I specified remote subnet 192.168.112.0 and the mask 255.255.255.0.

Once the connection is established, that route is automatically added. However, there other subnets that are available through that connection, such as 192.168.7.0 but I have to manually add these routes at the command line to make it work.

I believe the VPN server must be sending a list of routes because when I use Windows XP to connect to the VPN, routes for all those subnets are automatically added to the routing table.

Is there a way to have DD-WRT automatically add these routes when the connection is established? That was, if the network configuration changes behind the VPN server, I wouldn't have to manually edit the routing table on my DD-WRT.

Same thing for the DNS server, is there a way to avoid manually entering the DNS server to use for the VPN connection?

Answer (score 2):

When the ppp connection starts this script:

```
/etc/ppp/ip-up
```

is executed in your system. Note that there are some variables that are passed from the server. Read the last `for` statement, it will start a few more scripts:

```
#!/bin/sh
# This script is run by pppd after the link is established.
# It executes all the scripts available in /etc/ppp/ip-up.d directory,
# with the following parameters:
# $1 = interface name (e.g. ppp0)
# $2 = tty device
# $3 = speed
# $4 = local IP address
# $5 = remote IP address
# $6 = ipparam (user specified parameter, see man pppd)
ifconfig $1 mtu 1280 || true

cd /etc/ppp/ip-up.d || exit

for SCRIPT in *.sh ; do
        . ./"${SCRIPT}" "$@"
done
```

in the `/etc/ppp/ip-up.d` folder I have a file called `40-dns.sh`. It looks like this and it will set the `/etc/resolve.conf` with the DNS servers sent by the VPN server

```
#!/bin/sh    
# Handle resolv.conf generation when usepeerdns pppd option is being used.
# Used parameters and environment variables:
# $1 - interface name (e.g. ppp0)
# $USEPEERDNS - set if user specified usepeerdns
# $DNS1 and $DNS2 - DNS servers reported by peer

if [ "$USEPEERDNS" ]; then

        if [ -x /sbin/resolvconf ]; then
                {
                        echo "# Generated by ppp for $1"
                        [ -n "$DNS1" ] && echo "nameserver $DNS1"
                        [ -n "$DNS2" ] && echo "nameserver $DNS2"
                } | /sbin/resolvconf -a "$1"
        else
                # add the server supplied DNS entries to /etc/resolv.conf
                # (taken from debian's 0000usepeerdns)

                # follow any symlink to find the real file
                REALRESOLVCONF=$(readlink -f /etc/resolv.conf)

                if [ "$REALRESOLVCONF" != "/etc/ppp/resolv.conf" ]; then

                        # merge the new nameservers with the other options from the old configuration
                        {
                                grep --invert-match '^nameserver[[:space:]]' $REALRESOLVCONF
                                cat /etc/ppp/resolv.conf
                        } > $REALRESOLVCONF.tmp

                        # backup the old configuration and install the new one
                        cp -dpP $REALRESOLVCONF $REALRESOLVCONF.pppd-backup
                        mv $REALRESOLVCONF.tmp $REALRESOLVCONF

                        # correct permissions
                        chmod 0644 /etc/resolv.conf
                        chown root:root /etc/resolv.conf
                fi
        fi

fi
```

For the routes to be pushed in the routing table on connection estabilished you should be able to do a similar trick. Go to the pppd man pages to see the variable names that you need to use.

This code samples are from my Gentoo Linux PC, but this stuff is Linux generic so it will work also on DD-WRT.

Answer (score 1):

Although previous answer is correct for linux in general, you cannot edit or add files that easily on some ddwrt routers.

All 4 ddwrt routers I use generate these files when pptp client is run, making it impossible to just change or add files.

Here is a workaround that seems to work on most routers http://stadar.org/content/ddwrt-pptp-client-add-routes-after-connection